# dig & nslookup can't resolve local hosts unless I specify the (local) DNS server to use

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I am setting up a small private network within my University network. I have a Centos 6 box (**sun**) sitting between my private network and the university WAN. eth0 on the **sun** is connected to the WAN and eth1 to my private network via a netgear smart switch. **sun** acts as a router for the private network, forwards traffic from eth1 to eth0 using NAT configured using iptables. The clients on the private network (of which there is just at the moment, **mercury**) are assigned an IP, gateway etc and hostname via dnsmasq running on the **sun**. dnsmasq is configured to send a specific IP and hostname to the MAC address(es) of the client(s).

I have hardcode the hostname/IPs in `/etc/hosts` on **sun** only:

```
# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.42.1    sun sun.beowulf.iecs
192.168.42.2    mercury mercury.beowulf.iecs
```

At the moment, the IP address of eth0 (WAN facing) is assigned via DHCP (**sun** eth0 gets assigned the same IP all the time regardless; this is how the University does things but I'm in the process of getting this changed to allow me to assign a static IP). My `/etc/resolv.conf` on **sun** is:

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search biol.uregina.ca
nameserver 142.3.102.202
nameserver 142.3.100.15
```

which seems to be being overwritten when I reboot so I have the following `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf`

```
search beowulf.iecs biol.uregina.ca
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and have instructed dnsmasq to use it instead of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Change this line if you want dns to get its upstream servers from
# somewhere other that /etc/resolv.conf
resolv-file=/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf

# By  default,  dnsmasq  will  send queries to any of the upstream
# servers it knows about and tries to favour servers to are  known
# to  be  up.  Uncommenting this forces dnsmasq to try each query
# with  each  server  strictly  in  the  order  they   appear   in
# /etc/resolv.conf
strict-order
```

Mostly this setup is working. The problem I have (and I'm not sure it is a major one, but...) is that `nslookup` and `dig` both fail to resolve names for **sun** and **mercury** *unless* I inform these commands which DNS server to query:

```
# nslookup sun.beowulf.iecs sun.beowulf.iecs
Server:     sun.beowulf.iecs
Address:    192.168.42.1#53

Name:   sun.beowulf.iecs
Address: 192.168.42.1

# nslookup sun sun.beowulf.iecs
Server:     sun.beowulf.iecs
Address:    192.168.42.1#53

Name:   sun
Address: 192.168.42.1

# nslookup sun
Server:     142.3.102.202
Address:    142.3.102.202#53

** server can't find sun: NXDOMAIN

# nslookup sun.beowulf.iecs
Server:     142.3.102.202
Address:    142.3.102.202#53

** server can't find sun.beowulf.iecs: NXDOMAIN
```

The same output is given for **mercury** instead of **sun*. Representative `dig` output is:

```
# dig @192.168.42.1 mercury.beowulf.iecs

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> @192.168.42.1 mercury.beowulf.iecs
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 65090
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mercury.beowulf.iecs.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mercury.beowulf.iecs.   0   IN  A   192.168.42.2

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.42.1#53(192.168.42.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 25 12:05:31 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 54
```

and not working when I don't specify the nameserver to use:

```
# dig mercury.beowulf.iecs

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.23.rc1.el6_5.1 <<>> mercury.beowulf.iecs
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 29153
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mercury.beowulf.iecs.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           7988    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2014062500 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 142.3.102.202#53(142.3.102.202)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 25 12:05:37 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113
```

In the last example above (`dig`) the `SERVER: 142.3.102.202#53(142.3.102.202)` is the first DNS server in `/etc/resolv.conf` so by default **sun** seems to be using this nameserver instead of dnsmasq that I would have expected it to use because of the settings in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.

So, is this a problem? I can ping **sun** and **mercury** from **sun**, and connect to **mercury** from **sun** using SSH.

If this is a problem (or even if it isn't), is there a way to configure **sun** and `dnsmasq` running on it to resolve the private host names automatically?

Comment: Do you have a nameserver running on your localhost?

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Yes, dnsmasq running on the Centos box, **sun** in the above Q.

Comment: Appears you are querying different nameservers.  Appears  142.3.102.202 does not have any A records configured for the domain.  So I am not sure where you are managing records?

Comment: @jeffatrackaid Thanks again. Between your comment here and Iain's answer, I have realised my mistake. Whilst I may have instructed dnsmasq to not use `/etc/resolv.conf`, **sun** doesn't know about this and continues to use `/etc/resolv.conf`, which is being overwritten by `dhclient-script` when it asks for an IP address from the WAN DHCP server. FWIW, the private DNS information is being served from **sun** (192.168.42.1), but **sun** doesn't know this because of what is in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dig` (*domain information groper*)  and `nslookup` (*query Internet name servers interactively*) are tools that query name servers. Unless a specific name server is specified as a commandline argument they will query the name server(s) found in /etc/resolv.conf. They simply don't look at alternative sources of host information such as the `/etc/hosts` file or other sources specified in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

If you want to force all dns queries through dnsmasq on your **sun** host, the `/etc/resolv.conf` there should point to dnsmasq, i.e. it should look like:

```
#/etc/resolv.conf on sun
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

To prevent that file from getting overwritten when you restart the network interface eth0 edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`  and add the [option](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html) `PEERDNS=no`

Second in `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf` you're trying to configure dnsmasq to use itself  as the upstream name server `nameserver 127.0.0.1`... That file should look like:

```
#/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf
search beowulf.iecs biol.uregina.ca
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

if you want to use Google's name server. It might be a good idea to use the University name servers 142.3.102.202 & 142.3.100.15 there instead as it is not uncommon to have certain resources only visible from the campus network.

If your **mercury** host is configured by DHCP it should get it's configuration from dnsmasq and the `/etc/resolv.conf` there points to the dnsmasq name server on 192.168.42.1

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. I had come to realisation too that **sun** itself will use whatever is in `/etc/resolv.conf` to resolve names. I was conflating the dnsmasq configuration with what **sun** was actually using. Note the `8.8.8.8` in `/etc/dnsmasq-resolv.conf` was there just temporarily as when I edited it I didn't have the IPs of the University domain servers immediately to hand. I will specify those nameservers when I finalise this. To fully solve my problem, until the University assigns me a properly static IP, I'll need to stop `dhclient-script` overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`. Thanks again

Comment: Accepting this answer because it is more specific to my actual problem and contains more detail. That said, I diagnosed the problem (my mistaken thinking) from Iain's answer and comments from @jeffatrackaid.

Answer (score 4):

The 142.3.102.202 and 142.3.100.15 do not know anything about your local private network so they correctly return *NXDOMAIN*. These are also the default name servers for the system so when you don't specify a name server they will be used.

You will need to overwrite the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` and configure the nameserver directives to point to your local dnsmasq name server which in turn should be configured to forward queries it cannot answer upstream.

Comment: Thanks for this. If I temporarily insert `nameserver 127.0.0.1` into `/etc/resolv.conf` and comment out the other entries, then `dig` and `nslookup` work correctly. I hadn't fully groked that even though dnsmasq wasn't using `/etc/resolv.conf`, the computer **sun** was still using the information therein. So it seems to fully sort this out I'll need to work out how to stop `dhclient` overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` until I am assigned a static IP by the WAN admins.

Comment: @GavinSimpson this may be a way to set the nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3668/what-file-to-i-have-to-edit-to-make-static-dns-server-in-centos

Comment: Thanks again Iain; I too had just discovered that `PEERDNS=no` solution via a different route. Adding that to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` solved the overwriting of `/etc/resolv.conf` for me.